# Tailwind Utility Classes

Tags: javascript, directory, tailwind-css

[image: Directory Structure and Tailwind Configuration]

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The above code gives the following error when I try to run my project through npm run dev with a blank page opening up even though I'm just typing in "Hello World" right now -

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

I'd be glad if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking:

- You have actually used a utility class in any files covered by the `content` file globs. If you haven't yet, the warning is expected.
- Your `content` file globs are correct. You have spaces in some of your file extension brace listings. This would mean the braces expand to:

  - `src/**/*.js`
  - `src/**/*. ts`
  - `src/**/*. jsx`
  - `src/**/*. tsx`
    These would not match your `App.jsx` I see in your screenshot for example. You'd either need to rename your `App.jsx` to `App. jsx` (with the space) or more commonly, remove the spaces in the braces, `./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}` if you wanted Tailwind to scan the `App.jsx` you have open.